# Error shows when opening saved image in django admin

Tags: python, django

I am facing some very basic issue.
I saved some detail in my django model including a profile picture.
When i open django admin then i can saw i link for the image which i have saved.But when i click on that link it show me error.My image is not founding.
How can i resolve the issue.
settings.py

```
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'

MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(STATIC_ROOT, 'media')
```

link showing me in django admin

```
media/media/ind_kQRDi6b.jpg
```

when i hit enter to open this this image it hit `127.0.0.1/8000/media/media/ind_kQRDi6b.jpg`

And error show **Page not found**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django. Media Files not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39359104/django-media-files-not-found)

Comment: shouldn't that be 127.0.0.1/8000/media/ind_kQRDi6b.jpg

Answer (score 1):

Make sure that your url is correct. Like , `http://127.0.0.1:8000/media/image.jpg`